# DB select two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I've searched around and can't seem to understand how to get this to work. At least, not the way my code is written. What im having trouble doing is changing this:

```
// ...
$sql3 = new db;
$sql3->db_Select(DB_TABLE_ROSTER_TEAM_MEMBERS, "*", "team_id = ".intval($row1['team_id'])." ORDER BY member_team_order");

while($row3 = $sql3->db_Fetch()) {
// ...
```

...to something that orders by the column `status_order`, which is located in a different table `DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS`. So essentially I'm trying to include 2 tables in the same `SELECT` query, so that I can change the `ORDER BY`. Can anyone explain how this is done? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I'm going to try and explain this as much as I can. Hopefully someone will be able to explain to me in a way I can understand.

By default, this code is meant to grab the users and place them in their respective "team_id", then order them by a selectable drop down box that allows me to change the order. However, the part that orders the members is not working, so I decided I wanted to have it automatically order by the member status that is located in the other table. The other table holds the team names and team order, along with other data that is not needed right now. I didnt even know if this was possible.

There is another code a little further down that may help as well, as it shows the structure of the table. It's what gives the names color as seen on the site I mentioned.

Hopefully I've helped explain it a bit more.

**And some more requested by Johan**

Here is the structure of the two tables.

`roster_team_members` fields:

```
member_id
member_name
team_id
team_name
game_id
game_name
member_team_status
text_color
member_team_order
```

`roster_member_status` fields:

```
status_id
status_name
text_color
status_order
display
```

Iv decided to fix the manual member order. iv found an error while debugging. if i cant figure out how to fix it il pot another question. thank you all for your help. iv just decided to go another route that should prove to be easier.

Comment: could you provide a bit more info on firstly the other table in the query apart from DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS and also how that other table relates to DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS, please?

Comment: DB_TABLE_ROSTER_TEAM_MEMBERS includes the users, user team, and a few others but there is nothing in there that i want it to order by. in the DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS there are member ranks and rank orders that id like to order by. Im not really sure how to answer your question. but if you go here- http://teamdtk.com/e107_plugins/jbroster_menu/jbroster.php and look at for example squad 2, id like it to order by squads which is located in the DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS table.

Comment: Sarge88, Welcome to stackoverflow. If you want to get good quality answers you will have to write a good quality answer. The best way in this case is to: A: describe the tables involved **using ascii art**, B: describe the output you want **again using ascii art please** C: tell us very short why you want this and D: give us the query you've tried and failed with.  If you do this a 100% correct answer should appear within minutes.

Comment: thanks Johan. ok i will make a detailed description of what is in both of these tables and what i want todo. idk what you mean by ascii art but il do my best to make it easy to understand. give me a few min to complete...

Comment: IDK if this will help but full code is here- http://pastebin.com/KRGdy5Ve line 519 is what im trying to change. there is also potential code on line 575 that might be easier to order by.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `db_select()` method look like? Are you using Drupal?

Your raw SQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.link_column = table2.link_column AND table1.team_id = 'Your team ID' ORDER BY table2.member_team_order
```

Without knowing exactly how your `db_select()` method works I can't tell you exactly how to do this.

Comment: Im using a cms called E107, Im still new to php so im confused by what you mean by DB_Select method. Where would i find this?

Comment: The `db_Select()` method is defined in the class `db`. When you do `$sql3 = new db;` you are creating a new instance of a class called `db`, and when you do `$sql3->db_Select()` you are calling a method called `db_Select()` from the object `$sql3`, which has a class of `db`. Somewhere in your code, is there a whole bunch of code wrapped in something that looks like this: `class db { ...code here... }`?

Comment: -1 for using implicit joins, drop that anti-pattern, get out of 1989 and use explicit joins instead.

Comment: i think it may be located in another php file. i will try to find it. give me a min

I was unable to find anything like that in this code or the code that it "includes".

Comment: @Johan I can't argue with the principle, but I feel it makes it more readable (mostly because it is the way I learnt it in the first place, I suppose). Is there any noticable performance-related reason for this?

Comment: @DaveRandom, normally none whatsoever, with very complex queries it is easier for the query optimizer to select a smart appoach. The main problem is accidental cross joins, and the fact that you need to rearrange your query if you want to use left join instead of inner joins, plus the fact that if you want a cross join it's not self documenting. The explicit join syntax also separates the join criteria from the filter criteria (although both do filtering obviously)

Comment: i dont know if this is what you were looking for but i found this-
SELECT * FROM e107_jbClan_roster_team_members WHERE team_id = 2 ORDER BY member_team_order

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select a.*,b.rank
from DB_TABLE_ROSTER_TEAM_MEMBERS a INNER JOIN DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS b
ON a.member_id = b.member_id
order by b.rank;
```

I've had to make a guess that the linking column between DB_TABLE_ROSTER_TEAM_MEMBERS and DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS is called 'member_id' and that the column that you wish to rank by in the DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBER_STATUS is called 'rank'.

Comment: i dont even know where to start adding this lol. im used to simple db_select commands. the from and by and confusing. im a newb i know, but im doing my best to learn this stuff and sadly im not understanding much of this. makes me feel dumb lol

Answer (score 0):

In order to join two tables you use a `join` clause.

Something like:

```
SELECT booking.`date`, customer.name 
FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer ON (customer.id = booking.customer_id)
WHERE customer.name = 'Sarge' 
ORDER BY booking.`date` DESC
```

If you have to tables with the same layout you can use a `UNION`.

```
  SELECT customer_USA.name, customer_USA.country
  FROM customer_USA
UNION ALL
  SELECT customer_NL.name, customer_NL.country
  FROM customer_NL
```

This will merge all records for both tables in one big resultset.

I'd give you the proper query for your case, but I have no idea what you want and the links you've provided require too much study, killing the fun of the puzzle.

Comment: i think the info ur looking for is above. hopefully. im overwhelmed with code being answered so im still trying to wrap my head around all of this.